# Devops pipeline release to another tenant

Tags: azure-devops

We have two tenants for nonprod and prod resources, along with two separate directories. The devops project connects to the nonprod directory. We have container workload in app service. And uses build and release pipeline for ci cd. Question, how to release to the production tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to `Project Settings` -> `Service Connections`, and add a new service connection, choose `Azure Resource Manager` as the type, and then `Azure Resource Manager using service principal (manual)`, you should be able to specify everything you need to connect to the tenant and subscription to which you wish to deploy:

[image: New Service Connection]

Comment: Does the service principle need to be defined as multi tenant? Our security team not feel comfortable of security risks of doing so

Comment: No, because you're telling the service connection to log in using the specific tenant ID/service principal ID/key or certificate.

Comment: yes, this works, sorry i forget to grant the permissions

Comment: Where do you create the service principle?

Comment: In the target tenants (the prod and nonprod tenants). When the DevOps ADO tenant's service connection authenticates, it has the Tenant ID, SP ID, and SP key of the tenant it is connecting _to_.