# Subscriptions not visible in Azure DevOps (pipeline release to multi tenant)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As described in the post [Devops pipeline release to another tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492813/devops-pipeline-release-to-another-tenant), we created a manual service principal to a subscription in another tenant then the one connected to the Azure DevOps environment.

Our release pipeline also uses library -> variable groups.

The 'Azure Resource Manager using service principal (manual)' that was created according to the other post, doesn't appear in the 'Azure subscription' dropdown under the section 'Available Azure service connections'.

Same problem in the 'Azure subscription' dropdown on the 'Azure App Service deploy' page.

Is there a way around this?

It mainly seems that Azure DevOps isn't made for multi tenant releases and you can only force it by using Azure Lighthouse or Databricks.

Comment: It's more likely that the user doesn't have access to those service connections, so they are hidden.

Comment: For those who have the same, the service connections had as scope level 'management groups'. Apparently then they don't show up everywhere in DevOps. I made 2 new service connections on subscription scope level and then I could use them also in the variable groups.